# Work done in a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-fields

Say a particle is moving along a path $\gamma$ in a vector field, then the total work done by the force $\vec{F}$ on the particle is $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}{\vec F}.d\vec{r}$.

Say if this value where positive what would it mean? Would the particle have expended energy or received energy transferred by the force?

Answer (score 0):

This would belong more in physics stackexchange.

However, your integral means work done *by* the field, therefore, if it is positive, the field gives the particle energy, and if negative, then the field takes energy from the particle.